# jQuery on event not working for future selectors

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I have a modal window. Inside it there is a table with id **WebPartWPQ2** which will have three different classes in three different states. The classes being ***ms-applyfiltersinactive***, ***ms-applyfiltersactive*** and ***ms-applyfiltershoverover***. Initially, when the modal window pops up, the table will have *ms-applyfiltersinactive* class. Only on change of an option in the select box inside it, the class of the table changes to *ms-applyfiltersactive* and then on mouse hover the class changes to *ms-applyfiltershoverover*. On closing the window, the class of the table resets to *ms-applyfiltersinactive*.

The requirement is that I need to have a click event on the table only when it is active i.e. has a class *ms-applyfiltersactive* or *ms-applyfiltershoverover*.

I am using

```
$(document).on("click","#WebPartWPQ2 .ms-applyfiltersactive, #WebPartWPQ2 .ms-applyfiltershoverover", function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

This fails to attach the click event to the table. This might be because the class of the table then is *ms-applyfiltersinactive*.

If I use the following code

```
$(document).on("click","#WebPartWPQ2 table[class*='ms-applyfilter']", function(){
    alert("Clicked again");
});
```

the event is fired in all the three cases, which I do not want.

I have tried to filter out the selectors using *hasClass* and *is* events.

```
$(document).on("click","#WebPartWPQ2 table[class*='ms-applyfilter']", function(){
    alert($(this).is("table.ms-applyfiltersactive"));
});
```

But this returns the same boolean when the table has any class.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: We cannot help you if we don't know the HTML. A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be most helpful. If the selector does not work, it probably means that there are no elements with class `.ms-applyfiltersactive`. Since the event handler is bound to the `document`, it does not matter what classes the elements you want to listen on have at the time you bind the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML, I cannot use your current code.  However, I've created an example that should help.

I would suggest doing the following:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on("click","#WebPartWPQ2", function(){
    switch($("#WebPartWPQ2").attr("class")){
        case 'ms-applyfiltersinactive':
            //do something
            break;
        case 'ms-applyfiltersactive':
            //do something
            break;
        case 'ms-applyfiltershoverover':
            //do something
            break;    
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PKWKn/11/

Hope this helps!